# Retrieving mail from Yahoo! Mail through Thunderbird sometimes fails: "The POP3 mail server (pop.mail.yahoo.com) does not support UIDL or XTND XLST"

Tags: thunderbird, email-client, pop3, yahoo-mail, xslt

*Originally asked on [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), deleted on the original site upon request. Please don't vote to close.*

Once in a while, for periods of several hours to days at a time, I get the following error message from Thunderbird when I try to get mail from Yahoo! Mail:

> The POP3 mail server (pop.mail.yahoo.com) does not support UIDL or XTND XLST, which are required to implement the "Leave on Server", "Maximum Message Size" or "Fetch Headers Only" options. To download your mail, turn off these options in the Server Settings for your mail server in the Account Settings window.

Until the issue clears up, I cannot get my mail through Thunderbird and must fall back on the web interface. My Nexus 7 has no trouble fetching the mail. Why is this happening, and is there something I can do about this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you have two devices **why are you using POP3?**

Comment: IMAP is designed to keep all email server-side, while I prefer to maintain my email archives locally.